# PHP Loop through multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this in var_dump.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '08:40:00' => string '8:40 am' (length=7)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          '09:00:00' => string '9:00 am' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          '12:00:00' => string '12:00 pm' (length=8)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          '12:20:00' => string '12:20 pm' (length=8)
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          '12:40:00' => string '12:40 pm' (length=8)
      3 => 
        array (size=1)
          '13:00:00' => string '1:00 pm' (length=7)
      4 => 
        array (size=1)
          '13:20:00' => string '1:20 pm' (length=7)
```

Whats the best way to loop through this array to access the 2nd level elements (the clock times), WITHOUT assuming the sizeof the main array (currently 2).

Yes i'm seeking code assistance, but most examples on google are for arrays with string indexes like testarray['breakfasttimes'] and testarray['lunchtimes'].

Comment: `foreach` inside `foreach`?

Comment: The current size of the main array is 3, BTW, not 2... also: if the keys are strings, then you access them through strings, if they are ints, then you access them through strings, but the result is the same: `$array['foo']` access the _foo_ key, whereas `$array[0]` accesses the value of the 0 index...

Answer (score 2):

You would need a recursive function like this one

```php
function show_branch($branches, $level = 0, $index = null) {
    if (!is_array($branches)/* and $level == 2 */) {
        echo $index.' - '.$branches.' (level: '.$level.')';
        return;
    }
    $level++;
    foreach ($branches as $branch) {
        show_branch($branch, $level, $index);
    }
}

show_branch($tree);
```

This function browses your tree until the non array branches.
You can also add a condition if you want to see only the level 2.